# How to programmatically add code to a Sheet?

Tags: vba

I have some code that I added to a Worksheet

```
Right Click on the Sheet1 -> View Code -> Paste my code to the Module
```

How can I do this programmatically ?

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
'Then what ? ? ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would question your ultimate intent, since it may be more efficient to have a single copy of the code rather than a copy in each sheet, but....

```
Sub AddCode()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets("sheet2")
    Dim wb As Workbook:  Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim code As String:  code = "Sub Duh()" & vbCrLf & " debug.print(""I'm Here!"")" & vbCrLf & "End Sub"

    Dim lineCount As Integer

    With wb.VBProject.VBComponents(ws.Name).CodeModule
        lineCount = .CountOfLines
        If lineCount > 0 Then
            .DeleteLines 1, lineCount
        End If
        .AddFromString code
    End With
End Sub
```